# How can I keep input track log in shiny, then print it and save it?

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a shiny app which accept input and display it. How can I keep input more text, and keep the track?

```
setwd("G:/work/R_Prj/Learning-shiny")

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("TRY-1"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("txtInput", "Input to Display") 
    ),                                          
    mainPanel(
      paste("------------->"),
      textOutput("txtOutput"),                  
      textOutput("logg")                        
    )
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
logg <- NULL
  output$txtOutput <- renderText({
    if(nchar(input$txtInput)==0) {
        txx <- paste(input$txtInput,"not yet input")
      }else{
        txx <- paste(input$txtInput,"<--------")
      }
    txx
  })
  output$logg <- renderText({
    logg <- c(logg, input$txtInput)
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

`input$txtInput` as the box to accept the text input and `output$txtOutput` as the box for treated text. While the `output$logg` to collect the `input$txtInput`.

How can I collect the text inputed, print(or`txtOutput`) it and keep it for further process, like counting or even save the log?

I can think of 2 issues here. 1. how can it tell the input is end, and mark as a new record? 2. how can it be recorded and retrive? saving every input? then it go back to issue one.

[image: Nothing input]
[image: 1st input: sss]
[image: 2nd input, after erase 1st]

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the values of the `textInput` inside a `reactiveValues` which get updated when clicking a button. In the following example you initialize an empty `data.frame` and a counter which both get updated when clicking the button. All Inputs get stored in a the `data.frame`.

If you want would like to store this values after the session for reusage you could use a `bookmarkButton` for **local storage** or you could also store the values in an SQL-Database or a NoSQL-Database for **permanent storage**.

```
  library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("TRY-1"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("txtInput", "Input to Display"),
      actionButton("store", "Store value in dataframe")
    ),                                          
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(dfnew=data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 0)) ,count=1)

  storedvalues <- observeEvent(input$store, {
    if(nchar(input$txtInput) > 0)  {
      rv$dfnew <- rbind(rv$dfnew, df())
      rv$count = rv$count + 1
    } else {
    }
  })

  df <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      id = rv$count,
      value = input$txtInput
    )
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
      rv$dfnew
  })


})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks, I need a moment to digest the code. btw, I didn't any data store in the environment. Is that means, I can't retrive the inputed data as rds for further manipulation?

Comment: You could of course. Just use the read.rds statement inside the observeEvent statement to update the empty data.frame (`rv$newdf <- readRDS("file.RDS")`, I would initialize the data.frame with `NULL` then :-):

Comment: follow up question:  at the `rv$dfnew <- rbind(rv$dfnew, df())`, where does the df() come from? It works as retriving the privous data, and must not `the F distribution`.

Comment: it is created on code block below. A data.frame with 2 columns and one row.   df <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      id = rv$count,
      value = input$txtInput
    )
  })
. Are you familiar with reactivity? Reactive statements create a promise which has to be called like a normal function. That´s why you neet to write `df()` and not `df`

Comment: df() as a function and comes at the end of function? interesting! I thought every seld-defined function must come earlier before we call upon it. :-) no wonder I can't find it untill I go through all code blocks!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the existing answer, i have a prototype that could be of interest for you. 
It shows how to log input changes in shiny apps dynamically. All inputs are tracked without having to specify which inputs should be logged.

The code can be found here: https://github.com/Timag/ShinyInputLog.

Full code:

## How to log input changes in shiny apps

```
addListener <- '
  function checkVariable() {
    if (window.ip == true) {
      sendToUI.setinputUpdate(["connected", "connected", window.ip]);
    }
  }

  function Create(callback) {
    var inputUpdate = false;
    return {
      getinputUpdate   : function()  { return inputUpdate; },
      setinputUpdate   : function(p) { inputUpdate = p; callback(inputUpdate);}
    };
  }

  var sendToUI = Create(function(inputUpdate) {
    if (inputUpdate) {
      $.getJSON("//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?", function(data) {
        window.ip = JSON.stringify(data.ip, null, 2);
      });
      var val = inputUpdate[1].toString()
      // dont allow other input types than the ones in UI-input to be logged
      if(val.charAt(0) != "." && val != "logger"){
        // datatableoutput gives input changes on itial start
        if(val.substring(0,7) != "values_"){
          Shiny.onInputChange("logger", [inputUpdate, window.ip]);
        }
      }
    }
  });

  $(document).on("shiny:inputchanged", function(event) {
    sendToUI.setinputUpdate([event.value, event.name]);
  });

  $(document).on("shiny:connected", function(event) {
      $.getJSON("//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?", function(data) {
        window.ip = JSON.stringify(data.ip, null, 2);
      });
      setTimeout(checkVariable, 100);
  });

  $(document).on("shiny:disconnected", function(event) {
    sendToUI.setinputUpdate(["disconnected", "disconnected"]);
  });

'

if(!file.exists("log.csv")){
  log <- data.frame(inputVal = "", inputId = "", UserIp = "", time = "")
  write.table(log, "log/log.csv", sep = ";", append = TRUE,  row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)
}


# 

library(shiny)

# Define UI for slider demo application
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(addListener))),
  #  Application title
  titlePanel("Input Logger"),

  # Sidebar with sliders that demonstrate various available
  # options
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # Simple integer interval
      sliderInput("integer", "Integer:",
                  min=0, max=1000, value=500),

      # Decimal interval with step value
      sliderInput("decimal", "Decimal:",
                  min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.5, step= 0.1),

      # Specification of range within an interval
      sliderInput("range", "Range:",
                  min = 1, max = 1000, value = c(200,500)),

      # Provide a custom currency format for value display,
      # with basic animation
      sliderInput("format", "Custom Format:",
                  min = 0, max = 10000, value = 0, step = 2500,
                  pre = "$", sep = ",", animate=TRUE),

      # Animation with custom interval (in ms) to control speed,
      # plus looping
      sliderInput("animation", "Looping Animation:", 1, 2000, 1,
                  step = 10, animate=
                    animationOptions(interval=300, loop=TRUE))
    ),

    # Show a table summarizing the values entered
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("values")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    input$logger
    if(!is.null(input$logger)){
      inputLog <- c(input$logger, as.character(Sys.time()))
      # some input give double values - shorten to one string to fit it in the data table
      if(length(inputLog) == 5) inputLog <- c(paste(input$logger[1:2], collapse = "-"), input$logger[3:4], as.character(Sys.time()))
      # wait till file was updated
      Sys.sleep(0.3)
      write.table(as.data.frame(rbind(inputLog)), "log.csv", sep = ";", append = TRUE,  row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
    }
  })

  sliderValues <- reactive({

    # Compose data frame
    data.frame(
      Name = c("Integer", 
               "Decimal",
               "Range",
               "Custom Format",
               "Animation"),
      Value = as.character(c(input$integer, 
                             input$decimal,
                             paste(input$range, collapse=' '),
                             input$format,
                             input$animation)), 
      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  }) 

  output$values <- renderDataTable({
    input$logger
    data <- as.data.frame(read.table("log.csv", sep = ";", header = TRUE))
    return(data[dim(data)[1]:1, ])
  }, options = list(lengthMenu = c(10, 20, 50), pageLength = 10))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
#runApp(shinyApp(ui, server), launch.browser = TRUE, display.mode = "showcase")
```

Comment: AWESOME! the `addlistener` seems not written in R style, but in C++? That's fasnating. Yet I need more time to digest. Unfortunately, I can only guess by now.